# Creating variable distance buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, buffer, polygon-creation

I would like to create variable distance buffers for some points in QGIS 3.4.

I have seen in previous posts that there used to be a tool for this in older versions of QGIS, but that this tool wasn't continued in the following update.

Is there a way to create buffers based on information from a column of the attribute table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's now part of the ["Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) tool. You can now enter a buffer value in the distance text box or you could click on the button on the right of the distance text box to set a variable distance buffer (by selecting *a numerical field* or with an expression)

[image]